# how can I show news one by one horizontally?

Tags: php, mysqli

code:

```
<?php
   $query = "select * from latest_news limit 0,10";
   $fet = mysqli_query($link,$query);
   while ($fetch = mysqli_fetch_array($fet)) 
    {
      $news_title = $fetch['news_title'];
    }
?>
```

html code:

```
<marquee onmouseover="this.stop();" onmouseout="this.start();">
    <h3 id="news-h3"><?php echo $news_title; ?></h3>
</marquee>
```

I am diplaying news_title using marquee but here only one data are showing. I want to display all news_title one by one. So, how can I do this.

Thank You

Comment: because your showing only one result. use in loop to show all titles.

Comment: If I put h3 tag inside the loop then it show all ten result but I want news diplay one by one

Comment: I answered with code, check below.

Comment: The <marquee> element is obsolete and must not be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what you want.

```
<marquee onmouseover="this.stop();" onmouseout="this.start();">
    <?php
        $query = "select * from latest_news limit 0,10";
        $fet = mysqli_query($link,$query);
        while ($fetch = mysqli_fetch_array($fet)) 
        {
          $news_title = $fetch['news_title'];
          ?>
            <span id="news-h3"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($news_title); ?></span>
          <?php
        }
    ?>
</marquee>
```

Use CSS to style news span. If you want to use h3 tag then style it also like:

```
<style>
h3 {
   display: inline;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try rewriting your code so your query results is displayed within your marque. For example, using your code:

```
<marquee onmouseover="this.stop();" onmouseout="this.start();">
    <?php
        $query = "select * from latest_news limit 0,10";
        $fet = mysqli_query($link,$query);
            while ($fetch = mysqli_fetch_array($fet)) {
                echo '<h3 id="news-h3">'.$fetch['news_title'].'</h3>';
            }
    ?>        
</marquee>
```

Hope this works for you!